# How to force java SSLContext to use TLSv1.1

Tags: java, java-8, jersey-client, jetty-9, sslcontext

**How do I get a jersey client to use TLSv1.1?**
I'm trying to force a com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties (jersey client code eventually goes to this class) to use **TLSv1.1** (or TLSv1) to write test code that confirms a server's protocols.
As I setup the client, I do the following:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
context.init(null, trustAll, new SecureRandom());
HTTPSProperties props = new HTTPSProperties(hv, context);
clientConfig.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, props);
```

Inside HTTPSProperties (I downloaded the 1.x source so this may be wrong) I see:

```
public void setConnection(HttpsURLConnection connection) {
    if (hostnameVerifier != null)
        connection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
}
```

If I use `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");` instead, the code works fine. I've tried add `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");` but it still doesn't work. The code above gives the stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1580)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
        ... 22 more
```

**My server** (Jetty 9.4.41) thinks it is allowing TLSV1.1. When I dump the sslFactory I get:

```
I. 2021-09-29 16:37:59. [main] SSL context: Server@239105a8[provider=null,keyStore=file:***,trustStore=null] -
STOPPED
    +> trustAll=false
    +> Protocol Selections
    |  +> Enabled size=3
    |  |  +> TLSv1.1
    |  |  +> TLSv1.2
    |  |  +> TLSv1.3
    |  +> Disabled size=3
    |     +> SSLv2Hello - ConfigExcluded:'SSLv2Hello', ConfigIncluded:NotSelected
    |     +> SSLv3 - ConfigExcluded:'SSLv3', ConfigIncluded:NotSelected JVM:disabled
    |     +> TLSv1 - ConfigExcluded:'TLSv1', ConfigIncluded:NotSelected JVM:disabled
    +> Cipher Suite Selections
       +> Enabled size=39
       |  +> TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       |  +> TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
       +> Disabled size=6
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
          +> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - ConfigExcluded:'^TLS_RSA_.*$'
```

**Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I dumped the SSLContext:
Protocol: TLSv1.1
Provider: SunJSSE version 1.8
SupportedSSLParameters: Protocols={"SSLv2Hello","SSLv3","TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"}

Comment: Now to figure out why the server isn't answering TLS 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the question to **how do I force a client to use TLSv1.1**

I gave up using the jersey client and just used HttpsURLConnection. Turns out using the System.setProperties wasn't a good ideal but the Diagnostics link from Tasos P. gave me ViewMyClient from SSL Labs.

Code below results in a report that SSL 3, TLS 1.0, and 1.1 are available but TLS 1.2, 1.3 and SSL 2 are not.

```
// Using these breaks things!
//System.setProperty( "https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1" );
//System.setProperty( "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1" );
String requestedProtocol = "TLSv1.1";
testOutput.reportHeader( "SSLLabs " + requestedProtocol );

SSLContext cx = SSLContext.getInstance( requestedProtocol );
cx.init( null, trustAll, new SecureRandom() );
testOutput.report( "Protocol: " + cx.getProtocol() );
testOutput.report( "Provider: " + cx.getProvider().toString() );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters p = cx.getSupportedSSLParameters();
sb.append( "Protocols={" );
for( String s : p.getProtocols() ) {
    sb.append( s ).append( ',' );
}
sb.append( '}' );
testOutput.report( "SupportedSSLParameters: " + sb.toString() );
testOutput.report( "" );

int read;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
final URL url = new URL(
    "https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html" );
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory( cx.getSocketFactory() );
conn.setHostnameVerifier( hv );
try {
    testOutput.report( "Response Message: " + conn.getResponseMessage() );
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    File file = new File( filename );
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream( file );

    while( (read = in.read(bytes)) != -1 ) {
        outputStream.write( bytes, 0, read );
    }
    outputStream.close();
    in.close();
    testOutput.report( "File " + filename + " written." );
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    testOutput.reportException( ex );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Jersey 3 official documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/client.html#d0e5078) you can use the [SslConfigurator](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/SslConfigurator.html) and build the SSL Context as in:

```java
SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
    //...
    .securityProtocol("TLSv1.1");

 SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
```

The SSLContext supported security protocols are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext).

If the problem persists, you should follow the *standard* [diagnostics](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/diagnosing-tls-ssl-and-https). Pay extra attention to `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` which controls the underlying platform TLS implementation as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization).

Finally, you can resort to `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` and explicitly disabled TLSv1 with `-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,TLSv1`. Note however that this will affect *all* TLS connections.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using an old lib that is built on top of com.sun.jersey.client so there isn't a SslConfigurator class.